# How to parse received response

Tags: ios, json

I am very new to iOS application development and I am getting the below response from the server:

```
"[{\"EmployeeID\":\"000001\",\"EmplyeeName\":\"ABCD EFGHI\"},
{\"EmployeeID\":\"000002\",\"EmplyeeName\":\"ADGHT ASASASAS\"}]"
```

Please anybody help me out on how to use employee ID and employee name in my application.

Comment: please post your url...

Comment: What did you try? Did you do *any* research before posting the question?

Comment: @Martin R: I did too much research and I am not getting proper solution thats why I posted this question.

Comment: But then you should show what you have tried. Show your code, what results you got, and where you have problems!

Comment: NSURL*url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXXXXXXX.sr/LoginAuth.svc/Employee"];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request  = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
 if (request)
 {
  [request setURL:url];
  connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
 }
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response;
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

Comment: - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection
    didReceiveData:(NSData*)data;
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError*)error;
{    NSLog(@"WHOOPS! Something went wrong");
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:error.description                                            delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alert show];
}

Comment: - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
 NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"Received data %@", s);
 
    
    NSData* response = webData;
    
    NSArray *entries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:nil];
    
    for(NSDictionary* entry in entries) {
        NSString* employeeID = [entry objectForKey:@"EmployeeID"];
        NSLog(@"Print %@", employeeID);
    }}

Comment: MARTIN here is my code please answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON data looks like "nested JSON", which means that you have to deserialize it twice.

The first deserialization extracts a string from your JSON data:

```
NSData *response = ...; // your data
NSError *error;
NSString *innerJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
                              options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

Now `innerJson` is the string

```
[{"EmployeeID":"000001","EmplyeeName":"ABCD EFGHI"},{"EmployeeID":"000002","EmplyeeName":"ADGHT ASASASAS"}]
```

which is again JSON data. The second deserialization extracts the array:

```
NSArray *entries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[innerJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                              options:0 error:&error];
```

And now you can access it like

```
for (NSDictionary *entry in entries) {
    NSString* employeeID = [entry objectForKey:@"EmployeeID"];
    NSLog(@"%@", employeeID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin R and Alex it's working seamlessly.

Comment: Technically it's only "escaped", not "nested".  But the above use of NSJSONSerialization is one way (of several) to "unescape" it.

Comment: @HotLicks: If `[{"foo":"bar"}]` is sent from the server as `"[{\"foo\":\"bar\"}]"` then 1) all quotation marks are escaped *and* 2) the result is wrapped in quotation marks. That's why I thought of it as a JSON string object whose value is (in this case) a JSON array object, and chose the term "nested JSON". - Surely there are other ways, but NSJSONSerialization seemed the easiest and least error-prone to me, for example if `["foo\"bar"]` is sent from the server as `"[\"foo\\\"bar\"]"`.

Comment: The only two legal outer structures for a JSON string are "object" (dictionary) and "array".  "String" is not legal standing alone, which is why you must specify "AllowFragments" to get the parser to accept it.  (But using NSJSONSerialization to "unescape" the string is fine, though there are no doubt faster methods, if you're really into efficiency.)

Comment: @HotLicks: I think that I see now what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSData *response = ...;
NSArray *entries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:nil];

for(NSDictionary* entry in entries) {
    NSString* employeeID = [entry objectForKey:@"EmployeeID"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks ALex, no luck with above code could you please let me know where I am wrong in the below code?

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];NSLog(@"response %@", s);    
    NSData* response = [s dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *entries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:nil];
    for(NSDictionary* entry in entries) {
        NSString* employeeID = [entry objectForKey:@"EmployeeID"];
        NSLog(@"print %@", employeeID);
    } }

Comment: why you did not use "NSData* response = webData;"?

Comment: Used nut no luck showing no result

Comment: Have you tried Martin R "nested JSON" solution? It looks like it should work

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin R and Alex it's working seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Look JSON Parser your response is JSON so you need to get that data from json.

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"<YourURL>"];

NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError * error;

NSMutableDictionary  * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

NSLog(@"%@",json);


NSMutableArray * EmployeeID=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSMutableArray * EmployeeName=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSArray * responseArr = json[@"geonames"];

for(NSDictionary * dict in responseArr)
{

[EmployeeID addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"EmployeeID"]];
[EmployeeName addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"EmplyeeName"]];

}
```

now you get the EmployeeID,EmployeeName array now you can used anywhere where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

[NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData%3aoptions%3aerror%3a)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
NSData* yourData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: yourURL];
NSarray* yourJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

Hope this help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
NSDictionary *myJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```