# Getting error when parsing JSON iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

After get string from web service, i need to parse them. But something is going wrong.

Here is my code;

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    NSLog(@"response String = %@",responseString);

    NSData *tempData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSString *innerJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tempData
                                                          options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];      

    NSLog(@"innerJson = %@",innerJson);
    NSArray *entries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[innerJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                       options:0 error:&error];

    NSLog(@"entries = %@",entries);

    for (NSDictionary *entry in entries) {
        NSLog(@"entry = %@",entry);
        NSString *message = [entry objectForKey:@"message"];
        NSLog(@"message = %@",message );

        NSString* result = [entry objectForKey:@"result"];
        NSLog(@"result = %@", result);

    }
```

Here is my output;

```
innerJson = {"result": false,"message":"message!"}//I need parse this string.
entries = {
message = "message!";
result = 0;
}
entry = message
```

I am taking error in `for` loop.
What am i doing wrong?
Thanks for interest and advice.

Comment: Error is this :-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x971d640
2014-01-23 23:29:41.028 postData[10311:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x971d640'

Comment: That pretty obvious. You have an NSString, not an NSDictionary.

Comment: But 'entries' is NSArray. How can i parse it?

Comment: Entries should be NSDictionary not NSArray.

Comment: The error says you're doing objectForKey on an NSString, clear and simple.  What I can't figure out is what the heck you think you're doing with the second JSONObjectWithData.  Please post *the original* JSON source as you received it, in `responseString`, so we can make heads or tails of this.

Comment: Yes but the array contains different objects. Your code assumes it just has dictionaries.

Comment: If indeed you really do have "inner" JSON, `entries` is a NSDictionary and the loop you're doing will return their keys (as NSStrings).  One of the keys will be "result" and the other will be "message".

Comment: response String = "{\"result\": false,\"message\":\"message! \"}"//This is my original response string and i found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859037/how-to-parse-received-response and i used for my code.

Comment: So you just used the first NSJSONSerialization pass to "unescape" the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the line

```
NSArray *entries = [NSJSONSerialization
```

you assign the result to NSArray, and your JSON object is a dictionary, so you should assign to NSDictionary. Then the `for` loop is unnecessary - you can do:

```
NSDictionary *entries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[innerJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&error];

NSLog(@"entries = %@",entries);
NSString *message = [entries objectForKey:@"message"];
NSLog(@"message = %@",message );

NSString* result = [entries objectForKey:@"result"];
NSLog(@"result = %@", result);
```

Read more details in NSJSONSerialization documentation.

Comment: I think it does. The loop for (NSDictionary *entry in entries) really loops through NSDictionary, so the key (which is a string) is assigned to variable of NSDictionary type, and then wrong selector is sent to it.

Comment: No, the problem is that entries contains different types of objects but the code assumes it only contains dictionaries.

Comment: The problem is that the user assumes an array when it's a dictionary, and then proceeds to loop when a loop is unnecessary to fetch those two values.

Comment: @maddy: NSJSONSerialization documentation clearly says: the top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary. In this case it is NSDictionary. And the result of JSONObjectWithData is assigned to NSArray. The rest is outcome of this problem.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka: Thanks for answer,it is working now, but i have one more question,if service send more than one,what i am going to do? Example:{"ProductID":311,"ProductName":"Osteoflex "},{"ProductID":312,"ProductName":"Flexvisc"}

Comment: I guess in your example you missed [ ] characters. Anyway, in for JSON of such structure your original code will work, since in this case you will get NSArray consisted of two NSDictionary objects.

Comment: @TwentyThr23 - There's a trick I've used when the data might be a single dictionary or an array of dictionaries:  Test the data type received with `isKindOfClass`.  If it's an array then just pass it through as `myJsonArray` or whatever.  If it's a dictionary, create a single-entry NSArray containing the dictionary and assign that to `myJsonArray`.  Then the bulk of your code doesn't care which you got.

Comment: Actually, i asked similar question before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053976/wcf-rest-service-get-post-ios and i got this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859037/how-to-parse-received-response, it worked perfectly, but in this example, it didn't work, i used same things. Btw thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure - but I guess this code should work for you:

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSLog(@"response String = %@",responseString);
NSData *tempData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
/* assuming it is a dictionary */
NSDictionary *inner = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tempData
                                                      options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
NSLog(@"inner = %@",inner);
for(id key in inner) {
    id value = [inner objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"key=%@, value=%@", key, value);
}
```